# Akka Version Issue

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, akka, version

I am using Akka for my project.

Here, the ***Dependencies.scala***

```
import play.sbt.PlayImport.caffeine
import sbt._

object Dependencies {

  val akkaActorVersion      = "2.6.19"


  val akkaCluster       = "com.typesafe.akka"      %% "akka-cluster"        % akkaActorVersion
  val akkaProtobuf      = "com.typesafe.akka"      %% "akka-protobuf"       % akkaActorVersion
  val akkaRemote        = "com.typesafe.akka"      %% "akka-remote"         % akkaActorVersion

  val clientAPIDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
     Dependencies.akkaCluster,
     Dependencies.akkaProtobuf,
     Dependencies.akkaActorType,
    caffeine
  )

}
```

****Error**:-**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are using version 2.6.19 of Akka, but it appears you (perhaps indirectly) also depend on older versions of related artifacts. You can solve this by adding an explicit dependency on version 2.6.19 of the [akka-cluster, akka-protobuf, akka-remote] artifacts to your project. Here's a complete collection of detected artifacts: (2.5.25, [akka-cluster, akka-protobuf, akka-remote]), (2.6.19, [akka-actor, akka-actor-typed, akka-protobuf-v3, akka-serialization-jackson, akka-slf4j, akka-stream]). See also: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/binary-compatibility-rules.html#mixed-versioning-is-not-allowed
[error]
```

**NOTE** - I even tried the solution of this also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160905/akka-testkit-error-with-ambigous-version-error), i.e., adding all mentioned akka dependencies in the error message but still getting the same error.

Comment: I think your `Dependencies.scala` code is not complete and there is a dependency that brings akka `2.5.25` into you project. Also akka 2.5 and 2.6 are not compatible so you may get linkage errors when trying to use libs compiled against akka 2.5. You should find what lib brings 2.5 and update it also. Try it with this command `sbt module/Compile/dependencyBrowseTree`, where module is a subproject of sbt where akka is used

Comment: I just noticed that you have `play` sbt plugin. It might be the one depending on old akka. Make sure to use the one compatible with akka 2.6.x. Also the latest akka version released under opensource license is 2.6.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `sbt dependencyTree` and then grepping through it for one of the conflicting libraries, such ask `akka-cluster`.

As others have mentioned, somewhere you have a dependency on an older version of Akka. I agree with Ivan, that it is likely in your Play import, but the dependency tree could help you confirm that and potentially point you towards resolving it.